# How to make new notification replace older for the same Android app, when it is in background

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase to send a notification to my Android app.

When I receive a notification in foreground the method `onMessageReceived()` is called. If another notification arrives at the same time in the same app, it replaces the older one and shows only the last message.

On the other hand when the application is in background, I see multiple notifications.

I want the notifications to replace the previous ones, in background too. I've tried with collapse-key but it only works when the phone is offline.